# Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) Sinch API

Tags: android, sinch, android-sinch-api

i just updated my Android App to the last version of Sinch API. The new version is 3.9.9.

When i used the version 3.9.8 i could call perfectlly, but when i upgraded, its stops to work.

This error Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) shows when i try to start a client.

This is the error:

```
11-02 23:00:45.171 1634-1729/com.interonapp.interon E/rtc: #
                                                           # Fatal error in ../../../webrtc/modules/utility/source/helpers_android.cc, line 51
                                                           # Check failed: !jni->ExceptionCheck()
                                                           # Error during GetMethodID: initPlayout, (II)V
                                                           #
11-02 23:00:45.171 1634-1729/com.interonapp.interon A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 1729 (Thread-26695)
```

And here is my code:

```
    if (mSinchClient == null) {
        mSinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder()
                .context(this.getApplicationContext())
                .applicationKey(APP_KEY)
                .applicationSecret(APP_SECRET)
                .environmentHost(ENVIRONMENT)
                .userId(user.getSinchId())
                .build();

        mSinchClient.checkManifest();

        mSinchClient.setSupportCalling(true);
        mSinchClient.startListeningOnActiveConnection();
        mSinchClient.getCallClient().setRespectNativeCalls(false);

        mSinchClient.addSinchClientListener(new MySinchClientListener());
        mSinchClient.getCallClient().addCallClientListener(new SinchCallClientListener());
        mSinchClient.start();
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your report. Please verify that you have in fact updated both the native libraries and the jar, and that the old jar is not lying around.
The reason for this is that this method signature has changed from (II)V to (II)Z.

If you believe everything is upgraded correctly, let us continue in more detail over email. Please send us the full logcat log with the error reproduction to support@sinch.com

Comment: i will check! Thanks!